# Erro em Instalação do componente JEDI no Delphi Berlin (10.1)

Tags: delphi, componentes

Estou tentando instalar os componentes do JEDI no Delphi Berlin 10.1 em meu ambiente, porém, estou recebendo um Erro de compilação na bpl "JvCore240". 
A instalação do JCL se dá normalmente, sem erro algum, mas quando tento instalar o JVCL (que depende da instalação do JCL), me aparece esse erro de compilação e eu não consigo instalá-lo;

> JvCore.dpk(2364) Fatal: F2063 Could not compile used unit 'JvAppIniStorage.pas'

Procedimentos executados para possíveis resoluções:

- Executo o 'install.bat' sempre como Administrador
- A versão do JEDI é compatível com o Berlin (o mesmo componente já foi instalado em outro ambiente, e está funcionando 100%)
- Versões anteriores do Delphi já foram desinstaladas para evitar possíveis conflitos.
- Delphi Berlin 10.1 já foi reinstalado
- Já tentei instalar manualmente os pacotes em '.dpk' pelo próprio Delphi e o mesmo erro é apresentado na Unit 'JvAppIniStorage.pas'

Imagem do Erro no instalador:

[image: Erro durante a instalação do JVCL]

Comment: Consegui resolver. 
Por algum motivo, o instalador do JCL estavam pegando o path da versão anterior do JEDI para adicionar as 'Library Paths' do Delphi. 
Ou seja, ao invés de utilizar o path correto que seria "(...)Jedi\jcl\packages\D24\" para compilar os pacotes, o instalador estava passando a pasta "D23\" para Library Path do Delphi, o que ocasionava em um erro de versão na Instalação do Componente(JVCL).

A instalação do JCL estava compilando a versão do Delphi Seattle e o JVCL estava compilando sua versão do Delphi Berlin, e isso ocasionava esse erro de incompatibilidade.

Comment: Não há necessidade de adicionar RESOLVIDO  no titulo, mas você pode postar sua solução como resposta no campo abaixo, assim, poderá servir para outros com problema semelhante :)

Answer (score 1):

DIFICULDADES EM INTALAR JEDI NO DELPHI BERLIN

•   Tinha 2 Delphi (Delphi 7 e o Delphi Berlin versão profissional, todos comprados e registrados)

•   Desabilitei o antivírus

•   Utilizei instaladores atualizados de jcl e jcvl. 
•   https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&sp=nmt4&u=http://jcl.sourceforge.net/daily/&usg=ALkJrhi-04vdiUEMu5Bxze22OR81_MRjsA
•   https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&sp=nmt4&u=http://jvcl.sourceforge.net/daily/&usg=ALkJrhhg967ZI5hHblGMDmhQ4C2pNKTQng

•   Compilar o Delphi 7 travava (abaixo o detalhe). Por isso exclui ele, e deixei só para instalar no Berlin, ai deu tudo certo.

Detalhe dos problemas que impediam a instalação no Delphi 7
•   Ausência de BDCBDS...
•   O último foi um tal de dcc32.exe que tinha que ser trocado por uma nova versão encontrada em 
https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25419 mas que mesmo assim devia 
How to use:
1.-Copy the dcc32speed.exe into the $(DELPHI)\Bin directory.
2.- Replace "dcc32.exe" calls in your build scripts by "dcc32speed.exe"

Grato espero que outros possam serem orientados